# How do I open a web link and save the file in the same folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to write a VBA macro to open a web link and save the file in a folder. The following is my code:

```
Sub Performance()

    Workbooks.Open "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/XLY?period1=1411833600&period2=1569600000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=jUHds.etlZC"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/file.csv"

End Sub
```

However, the VBA macro doesn't work. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: "the vba macro doesn't work" - what does it do *instead* of working?

Comment: This is not constructive.

Comment: This is how it works here: you describe *exactly what happens* when you run your posted code (and how that is different from what you expected/wanted), and we use that information to try to help you fix it.  If that's not constructive, then I'm not sure what you'd prefer we do.